# G1xon multi effects pedal - can I hear the effected guitar along with the drum beats, through headphones, without an amp?

Tags: guitar-effects

I have a g1xon multi effects pedal on the way and for silent playing,and I was wondering could I plug it into my guitar and then hook up headphones without a amp and still hear the guitar and the effects along with the drum beat? And if not,then I imagin I could do the same thing as long as I have a amp for silent playing?

Comment: Since it has  an output (phones) port, you can. This isn't really the place to be asking questions such as this - not a lot of help to many - and info. is available on the Zoom site.

Comment: @Tim We do usually accept questions about how to use particular bits of equipment, unless things have changed recently..? If it's true that the info is available on the manufacturer's site, and that's the thing you think makes this question less useful, maybe that should be something we mention on the on-topic page.

Comment: @topomorto - I feel that info. on specific equipment, such as this, really has little value to site users, especially when that info. is readily available - and maybe it's a question that the OP should have had answered *before* ordering...?

Comment: @Tim quite possibly - all I'm saying is that at the moment, we say 'usage of specific music software or hardware' is on-topic. If you think that opens the doors too wide, perhaps it would be worth a meta question to discuss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - one of the main purposes of these 'amp sim + effects' boxes is to allow you to play without an amplifier, and (where a headphone socket is offered) through headphones. The purpose of the drum beats is to give you something to practice to, and as such they will also be audible through the headphones along with your guitar signal. I'd imagine anything you route into the unit through the 'aux in' jack can be mixed in too.

Answer (score 1):

Before setting up a DAW and ASIO soundcard I used the G1Xon a lot.

IIRC each sound patch can be set either with or without amp or cab simulation and the output can be set as either line or instrument (to plug into headphones or a (physical) amp). The sound level of the drums (and metronome) can also be set, for both playback and looping.

https://www.zoom-na.com/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/E_G1on_G1Xon.pdf doesn't seem to mention it though

If you ever need to connect the output as a soundcard to a DAW or to a stereo amp the G3/5(x) series is a better choice. Not battery powered though but if that's not a dealbreaker much better value both in terms of sound design, practising and recording. The sound design is much easier on a PC/Mac than on the floor or a table (racing through menus with 2 small buttons) and you can backup and restore all patches. G3/G5 can also send and receive MIDI which effectively makes it a (USB) MIDI footswitch as well.